# MIME для шрифтов ttf и otf

Tags: android, шрифты, mime, saf

До десятой версии андроид, через запрос SAF вводил тип "application/octet-stream" и в принципе все работало. Конечно показывало не только шрифты но и другие файлы, но работать можно было. В 10 версии файлы с расширением ttf и otf перестали быть активными.
И вот еще странность, загруженные на телефон с андроидом 9 версии, и импортированные в приложение, после обновления операционки до 10 версии, эти файлы оставались видны, а новые нет.
Указывал такие типы

```
        intent.setType("application/x-font-ttf");
        intent.setType("application/x-font-otf");
        intent.setType("application/font-sfnt");
        intent.setType("application/*");
```

Но ничего не помогает. В общем прошу совета как быть. Может кто сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Попробуйте запросить мим по расширению: `MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)`. Если вернёт что-то внятное, то использовать для запроса файла - если нет, то надо адресовать этот вопрос в AOSP - "Каким чудом мы можем получить файл нужного типа, если система этот тип не знает, добавить в систему его нельзя и по расширению запросить тоже нельзя?" Можно только положиться на адекватность юзера и запросить файл любого типа: `"*/*"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем все оказалось проще. Андроид 10 стал поддерживать MIME font, а значит в "application" их не видно.. Выяснено это было методом проб, так как документацию читать мы не приучены(.

```
 intent.setType("font/ttf");
```

И кстати, отф тоже видно.